# Latest articles structured data markup

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles, template-override, images

I have added microdata into every article manually and it works fine.
Now I want to insert them into the latest articles module.

To override the module in my template and I added:

```
<li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
    <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <span itemprop="name" content="...your organization name..."></span>
        <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <link itemprop="url" href="/images/KS.jpg">
            <meta itemprop="width" content="50">
            <meta itemprop="height" content="50">
        </span>
    </span>
    <span itemprop="author" content="...your name..."></span>`
```

and it works for organization, organization image - logo and author.

Next I added:

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->publish_up, JText::_('Y-m-dTh:m:s')); ?> " >
```

and it works for published date.

Now I have a problem when I try to add articles image markup. I added:

```
<?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <link itemprop="url" href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>">
    <meta itemprop="width" content="150">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="100">
</span>
```

and it works fine, but only for intro images through article image and links tab. I have my images in my html (not in image and links tab) and I want to extract image url from html. I have more than 400 articles and I prefer to extract the images from the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have preferred to just suggest some touch ups to your snippet, but there is too much for me to address in your answer as a comment and I'd rather explain fully.  Instead, I'll post this new answer which will review and clean up your assumed-working coding attempt for the benefit of you and future researchers.

1. You are declaring `$images = json_decode($item->images);`, then before ever using it, you are overwriting that same variable with `$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');`.  For this reason, you might as well, never declare it the first time.  Perhaps this is a typo while posting.  If this is correct: `$images = json_decode($item->images);`, then you probably mean to use `$dom->loadHTML($images->image_intro);`
2. You should try to separate your "processing" from your "displaying" as much as possible for clarity.  Rather than generating a dom document and extracting the desired data mid-way through writing your `<link>` tag, I recommend that you fully interrogate the `introtext` data, then -- if there is any data to feed into the link tag -- then write your span and link tags.  If there is no usable data, I assume you don't need to print the span and link tags.
3. You don't need the extra overhead of two dom documents.  You can perform both `getAttribute()` calls on the same element in one fell swoop.
4. If there is no `<img>` tag in the `introtext`, then `$images[0]` will generate a Notice because array element `[0]` does not exist.  Instead of performing a "truthy" check, use `isset()`.
5. There is no benefit to concatenating `''` (an empty string) before or after a variable.  Simply omit it -- it is just code bloat.  I don't know who is teaching this technique, but I see it every once in a while on Stackoverflow.

All together, transferring the first image's attributes from the introtext to your new tag is as simple as this:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDOcument;
$dom->loadHTML($item->introtext);  // or $images->image_intro  ...whatever you are actually calling it
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
if (isset($images[0])) {
    ?>
    <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <link itemprop="url"
          href="<?php echo $images[0]->getAttribute('src'); ?>"
          alt="<?php echo $images[0]->getAttribute('alt'); ?>">
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my question. 
I think is valid:

````
<?php $images = json_decode($item->images);
?>
<span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
<link itemprop="url" href="<?php // Create new DOMDocument object.
$dom = new DOMDOcument;

// Load article text into DOMDocument.
$dom->loadHTML($item->introtext);

// Get all images.
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// If article contains an image, get its URL.
$imageSrc = $images[0] ? $images[0]->getAttribute('src') : null;

// Output the image.
if ($imageSrc !== null)
{
 echo '' . $imageSrc . '>';
}
?>" alt="<?php // Create new DOMDocument object.
$dom = new DOMDOcument;

// Load article text into DOMDocument.
$dom->loadHTML($item->introtext);

// Get all images.
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

// If article contains an image, get its URL.
$imageSrc = $images[0] ? $images[0]->getAttribute('alt') : null;

// Output the image.
if ($imageSrc !== null)
{
 echo '' . $imageSrc . '>';
}
?>">```
````